# Are these two different phones listed in Google Drive's Backups?

Tags: samsung, google-backup

The following screenshot is from [Google Drive's Backups](https://drive.google.com/drive/backups).

[image]

> **SAMSUNG-SM-J327A backup**
>
> - Apps: 30 apps
> - Call history: 94 KB - Last backup: Oct 13, 2019
> - Device settings: 4 KB - Last backup: Oct 14, 2019
>
> **Samsung SAMSUNG-SM-J327A backup**
>
> - Apps: 32 apps
> - Call history: 101 KB - Last backup: Oct 13, 2019
> - Device settings: 4 KB - Last backup: Oct 13, 2019

They are listed as the same phone but one seems different with the number of apps.

How can I tell if these are two different phones?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check whether there is another phone (in this case with the same model) that used the same account by going to [Google Dashboard](https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard). From there select Android. The number of devices using the account will be shown and listed.

If there are 2 Samsung SM-J327A models, to differentiate between them, you can go [here](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) to use Find my device and compare the IMEIs of both devices by clicking on the info button.