# Is there a way to find the IMEI on a Pixel with a completely damaged screen?

Tags: screen, google-pixel, imei, google-pixel-2

A couple weeks ago my Pixel XL 2 (or Pixel XL, not sure) started to have black blotches all over the screen. They grow, enlarge and eventually engulf the entire screen. Now except for a sliver on the upper right corner, the screen is pitch black regardless if it is on or off. What kind of damage is this? There had been no physical damage to the phone. As far as I can remember, the phone has never been dropped or otherwise subjected to excessive physical forces.

I am trying to find the phone's IMEI, but I am not sure how to go about doing it without being able to see anything on the screen.

Also when it is plugged in to my laptop via a USB-C cord, my Windows 10 recognizes the phone, but I don't see an additional drive. How should I access the files on there? Is there a way to reset the phone and clear the data?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217684/247431) to retrieve the IMEI using Find my device, Open the link on your PC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can find IMEI of your damaged Pixel Device or any Android device if you have or had your google account logged in .

Check Google My Devices
or alternatively logon to Google Find my devices @ https://www.google.com/android/find

on your device list click the ( i ) information icon, you can see your device IMEI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another source of a phone IMEI and serial number is the package box the phone was bought in.

On the outside of the box there are usually the device serial number and IMEI printed as text and small 2D barcode.